# Proving $\operatorname{Im}\hat \Sigma \subseteq \operatorname{Im}\Sigma$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

Consider $\Sigma := \mathbb{E}[XX^{\top}]$ where $X \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and has a probability distribution $\mu$. The empirical counterpart is $\hat \Sigma := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_iX_i^{\top}$ where the $X_i$ are i.i.d from $\mu$. I would like to prove that $\mu-$almost surely

$$\operatorname{Im}\hat \Sigma \subseteq \operatorname{Im}\Sigma$$

I can see that $\operatorname{Im}\hat \Sigma \subseteq \operatorname{Span}\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$. And therefore it is easy to obtain the inclusion if $\mu$ is a discrete distribution. I struggle to prove the inclusion and characterise $\operatorname{Im}\Sigma$ when $\mu$ is not discrete. Could you point me to a reference or a hint to prove the inclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Sigma$ is symmetric, non-negative definite. Hence for all $v \in \text{Im}(\Sigma)^\perp = \text{ker}(\Sigma)$,
$$0 = v^\top \Sigma v = \mathbb E( (v^\top X)^2 )$$
This implies that $ v^\top X = 0$ a.s., so that $v^\top \hat \Sigma v =0$ a.s. as well. We deduce that $\text{Im}(\Sigma)^\perp \subseteq \text{Im}(\hat \Sigma)^\perp$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For clarification, the only property needed for the proof is the symmetry of $\Sigma, \hat \Sigma$, right? We do not need the fact that they are non-negative semi-definite.

Comment: I guess you don't need the non-negative semi-definiteness property for the argument to work but it is implied by the fact that $v^\top \Sigma v = \mathbb E( (v^\top X)^2 ) $